# Why is there a difference in filesize between using standalone bzip2 and pandas to_csv(, compression='bz2') function?

Tags: python, pandas, compression

I write out a csv using pandas, and apply bzip2 compression as follows:

```py
df.to_csv('/home/user/file.bz2', index=False, mode=writemode, header=header)
```

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv), `to_csv` infers from the filename that it needs to compress it using the `bzip2` method.

This ensures my ~100 MB CSV becomes ~ 23 MB.

However, if I decompress that `bz2` file, and run the resulting csv file through `bzip2` on my Mac with:

```sh
bzip2 /home/user/file
```

I get a file of ~7 MB! I get the same result if I run `bzip2` on Debian.

What can cause this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was not caused by an outdated pandas, but by incorrect expectations on my side.

I actually create the dataset by appending to the csv over the course of a day (every minute to be precise), as such:

```py
if first_data_of_the_day:
    df.to_csv('/home/user/file.bz2', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
else:
    df.to_csv('/home/user/file.bz2', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

This results in the larger ~23 MB file.

If I store the dataframe in memory over the course of the day (or in a csv), and only write out once to a compressed file at the end I get the smaller ~7 MB file, regardless of pandas version.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what is happening in your case, but bzip2 does support differing levels of compression that make tradeoffs between speed and size, and it's possible that the level being chosen via `pandas` is different from the default for the CLI tool. Using the `bz2` library:

```
In [118]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, [100000,5]))

In [119]: len(df.to_csv(None))
Out[119]: 2138880

In [120]: len(bz2.compress(df.to_csv(None).encode('ascii'), compresslevel=1))
Out[120]: 702709

In [121]: len(bz2.compress(df.to_csv(None).encode('ascii'), compresslevel=9))
Out[121]: 730415
```

This one is a little strange in that compression 9 is generally supposed to be slower but smaller, but it is a pretty simplistic dataset I've generated here so it may just be a bit of a degenerate case.

Comment: This might be the answer. If I run `bzip2 -1 file` where `-1` directs bzip2 to use the lowest compression I get a file of ~24 MB, similar to what pandas returns. When I run `bzip2 -9 file` to use the highest compression (= default for bzip2) I get the ~7MB file. Strange that pandas opts for the non-default compression...

Comment: Well, it seemed to be an issue between pandas `0.25.XX` and `1.X.X`... I've upgraded all packages and now it seems that pandas compresses using the default bzip2 compression level (i.e. `-9`).

Comment: Cool, sounds like the culprit then. FWIW, defaults would just be at a library level, so though `bz2` and the CLI tool opts for `-9` as the default, there's no reason that it needs to be globally default.